# Monitor Registry Changes during Installation

Tags: windows, installation, registry, monitoring, installshield

Is there a tool I can use to monitor registry changes that are made during installation of some software package?

I need to create an InstallShield installer including Crystal Reports runtime, and my prerequisite that works on Vista/Win7 doesn't work for XP. So I would like to have this tool running while running the Crystal Installer, and it tell me what registry changes occurred during installation.

Answer (score 2):

regshot is capable of creating a registry snapshot before and after installation and compare them, showing only differences. Of course, identifying the related changes is kind of work...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/